# alter table utilisateur_roles add constraint FK9lop304xtodorgho9w56lpjhn foreign key (utilisateur_id) references utilisateur (id)" via JDBC Statement

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, authentication, intellij-idea

*Error executing DDL "alter table utilisateur_roles add constraint FK9lop304xtodorgho9w56lpjhn foreign key (utilisateur_id) references utilisateur (id)" via JDBC Statement*

## this is class utilisateur :

```
package com.projetfd.projectfd.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Utilisateur {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String nom;
    private String motdepasse;
    private String email;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Role>roles;



    }
```

## this is class Role :

```
package com.projetfd.projectfd.entities;


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Entity
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String role;

    @ManyToOne
    private Utilisateur utilisateur;




}
```

## this is the application propreties :

```
server.port=8777
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasePFE?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

and when i run the the application she give me this error :

Hibernate: alter table utilisateur_roles add constraint FKgvjufa2i7moss3i9eh2i9yoaq foreign key (roles_id) references role (id)
2023-05-08T15:36:08.095+02:00  WARN 21924 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table utilisateur_roles add constraint FKgvjufa2i7moss3i9eh2i9yoaq foreign key (roles_id) references role (id)" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table utilisateur_roles add constraint FKgvjufa2i7moss3i9eh2i9yoaq foreign key (roles_id) references role (id)" via JDBC Statement
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:587) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:532) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1429) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1423) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at com.projetfd.projectfd.ProjectFdApplication.main(ProjectFdApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't create table `databasepfe`.`utilisateur_roles` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
... 38 common frames omitted

Comment: Hi. There is no question in your post. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.